# data duplication during parallel calls the same service springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Controler he call a serviceA

```
@Autowired
ServiceA serviceA;

public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<List<A>> getlistA(@RequestBody RequestA requestA) {
    List<RequestA> requestsListA = new ArrayList<>();
    requestsListA.add(requestA);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(serviceA.getListA(requestsListA), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And the serviceA   is annotated with @Service

```
@Scope
public class ServiceA {
…
}
```

When I send two requests in parallel  I find the data from the response of the first request in the response of the second request.

Example :
If I run two requestd not in parallel:

- respons of request A:     object1, object2, object3
- respons of request B:     object4 , object5

If I run two requestd in parallel:

- Result Query A: object1, object2, object3, object4, object5
- Result Query B: object1, object2, object3, object4, object5

```
If I have a class that is annotated with @Service, Spring create one instance of this to be shared in the JVM?
Or will every consumer class that autowires the service will get a new instance of the service?

Is it possible that for each time when I call the service it is forced to create a new instance


thank you



when I send two requestd in parallel i have all response merged . it's like singleton
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your issue might be inside of the serviceA. Whenever you use the @Service annotation on a class you can also define the spice of the component bean that service is creating by using the @Scope annotation. Without adding this last scope part the default for service is a singleton bean. If you scope it you can change this to be a prototype and that will give you one instance per request. With all this said, I don't think this is the way to go for you.

The real issue is that it sounds like you have a data leak between API calls which must mean you are updating a global/static variable somewhere which is causing the issue you are seeing. Please provide more detail on the service logic for further help.

Comment: thank you Games3D yes the probleme in a global variable  in service